Can't access express-session in socket.io
I am working on a project which uses socket.io and express-session packages.
Now the issue is i am unable to get session object which i have already set using login or authentication.
Below is my server.ts file
import SocketService from "./services/socket";
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");
const session = require("express-session");
const MongoStore = require("connect-mongo");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser"); // Import the cookie-parser package

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cookieParser());

//importing the dotenv package to use the environment variables
require("dotenv").config();
const port = process.env.NODE_ENV_PORT || 3000;

//importing the database connection
const conn = require("./db.ts");
const client = conn();

//defining cors options
const corsOptions = {
  origin: ["http://localhost:3000","http://localhost:5173"],
  methods: ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "HEAD", "OPTIONS"],
  credentials: true,
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200,
};

// setting up the session
const sessionMiddleware = session({
  name: "solace-session-id",
  secret: process.env.NODE_ENV_SESSION_SECRET,
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  store: MongoStore.create({ client: client,
    dbName: "solace",
    ttl: 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
    collectionName: "sessions"
  }),
  cookie: {
    maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7,
    sameSite: false,
    secure: app.get("env") === "production",
    httpOnly: true,
  },
})

app.use(sessionMiddleware);

// just for checking if the server is running
app.get("/", (req : any, res: { send: (arg0: string) => void; }) => {
  console.log("session id",req.sessionID);
  console.log("session",req.session)
  res.send("Hello World!");
});

//defining the routes for the app
app.use("/api/auth", cors(corsOptions), require("./routes/auth"));

const server = app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running at http://localhost:${port}`);
});

//socket service (Implementation is given below)
const socketService = new SocketService();

socketService.io.attach(server);

socketService.io.engine.use(sessionMiddleware);

socketService.initListener();

here i have made an socketService class in below file
SocketService.ts
import { Redis } from "ioredis";
import { Server } from "socket.io";

declare module 'http'{
    interface IncomingMessage{
        session: any,
        sessionID: string,
        sessionStore: any
    }
}

//importing the environment variables
require("dotenv").config();

const pub = new Redis({
    host: process.env.NODE_ENV_REDIS_HOST,
    port: parseInt(process.env.NODE_ENV_REDIS_PORT as string),
    username: process.env.NODE_ENV_REDIS_USERNAME,
    password: process.env.NODE_ENV_REDIS_PASSWORD,
});
const sub = new Redis({
    host: process.env.NODE_ENV_REDIS_HOST,
    port: parseInt(process.env.NODE_ENV_REDIS_PORT as string),
    username: process.env.NODE_ENV_REDIS_USERNAME,
    password: process.env.NODE_ENV_REDIS_PASSWORD,
});

class SocketService {
    private _io: Server;

    constructor() {
        this._io = new Server({
            cors: {
                origin: "*", // Allow all origins for development
                allowedHeaders: ["*"],
                methods: ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "HEAD", "OPTIONS"],
                credentials: true,
                optionsSuccessStatus: 200,
            },
        });
        sub.subscribe("chat");
    }


    //setting listener for the socket
    public initListener() {
        console.log("Initializing socket listeners");

        this.io.on("connect", (socket) => {
            ***console.log("Session: ", socket.request.session);***

            socket.on("message", async ({ message, email }: { message: string, email: string }) => 
                await pub.publish("chat", JSON.stringify({ message, email }));
            });
            //on disconnect
            socket.on("disconnect", () => {
                console.log("User disconnected");
            });
        });

        //on message received
        sub.on("message", (channel, message) => {
            console.log("Message received from channel: ", channel);
            this.io.emit("message", JSON.parse(message));
        });
    }
}

export default SocketService;

here when i connect to the socket in
this.io.on("connect",...) method i have tried to access the session
Here, i am able to get session as below:
Session :  Session {
   cookie: {
     path: '/',
     _expires: 2024-04-10T19:42:49.449Z,
     originalMaxAge: 604800000,
     httpOnly: true,
     sameSite: false,
     secure: false
   }
 }

but not able to get user object which i have set on login
Although i am able to access same session object in other express routes
I am following the documentation of socket.io https://socket.io/how-to/use-with-express-session
I am expecting that i should get the user object not only the cookies in session object.
I have used mongodb for storing sessions and redis for realtime chat.
Both chat and session storage is working perfectly.
I had some solution but it was based on old documentation , so i need solution based on current documentation

Okay, After 2 days i figured it out :
The issue was of express-session handling mainly
You need to configure express-session as below:
const sessionMiddleware = session({
  name: "solace-session-id",
  secret: process.env.NODE_ENV_SESSION_SECRET,
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  store: MongoStore.create({ client: client,
    dbName: "dbname",
    ttl: 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
    collectionName: "sessions"
  }),
  cookie: {
    maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7,
    sameSite: false, //false
    secure: app.get("env") === "production",
    httpOnly: true,
  },
})

as you can see mainly changes are in
resave : false
saveUninitialized:false

the issue was it was making new session object in MongoDB collection on each request which causing the sessionID different than the sessionID on which the user object actually setted
and also You need to include withCredentials: true while setting socket.io-client on client side as given below:
const [socket, setSocket] = useState<Socket | undefined>(undefined);

// initialize socket client 
useEffect(()=> {
    const _socket = io('http://localhost:5400',
    {
        withCredentials: true
    });

    _socket.on('connect', () => {
        console.log('Socket connected!');
        console.log(_socket);
        setSocket(_socket);
    });

    return () => {
        _socket.disconnect();
        setSocket(undefined);
    }
},[]);

and do not forgot to include CORS policy in both socket and server
For reference i have setted my CORS as below in socket.ts as below:
class SocketService {
private _io: Server;

constructor() {
    this._io = new Server({
        cors: {
            origin: ["http://localhost:3000","http://localhost:5173"], // Allow all origins for development
            allowedHeaders: ["*"],
            methods: ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "HEAD", "OPTIONS"],
            credentials: true,
            optionsSuccessStatus: 200,
        },
    });
    sub.subscribe("chat");

    // always remember to attach the server to the socket
    // and to initialize the listener
    // this.io.listen(5400);
}
// other code......
}

And do not forgot to include methods : ["OPTIONS"] in CORS since socket sends preflight request.
Thank You :)
